# Physical interpretation of Mandelstam variables with negative value

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics

Reading the text by Peskin-Schroeder "An introduction to Quantum Field Theory" the use of the Mandelstam variable as a function of angle of scattering in the center-of-mass frame

[image]

I was surprised that the t and u variables can be negative. I am convinced that this fact is profoundly linked to the fact that we are making the scalar product of two quadrivectors in Minkowsky's space, but I cannot understand what the interpretation of these two negative variables is.

I'm probably missing something and probably the meaning of the Mandelstam variables is not clear to me, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about timelike and spacelike four-vectors?

Comment: The sum of the 3 scattering channels would be $s+t+u=m_1^2+m_2^2+m_3^2+m_4^2$. It's easy to prove noting that the $p_{u}p^{u}$ is the mass squared in the center of mass frame - and using conservation of 4 momentum. See  Wikipedia.

Comment: @Javier Y.es, but I cannot make the connection with the situation described.